# ¿ Como Comparar valores iguales de 2 ListView y poner los valores iguales en otro?

Tags: c#, listview

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo dos listview el 1 y el 2, y quiero comparar los datos que sean iguales y me los ponga en un tercer listview pero pasando todos los datos tal cual solo juntando los que sean iguales, lo que me arroja es lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta saludos.

Comment: Y si además de lo que dice @Jorgesys, en vez de pegar una imagen pegas como texto la creación de ambos ListView y muestras el resultado esperado, seguro que nos resulta mucho más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score -1):

El resumen es que lo consigues con Linq, usando Intersec:

```
List<MiTipo> listaIguales = lista1.Intersect(lista2).ToList();
```

Con este código podrás ver cómo lo conseguirías, aunque yo lo haría desde el ViewModel:

```
// Creamos los tres listView
ListView listView1 = new ListView();
ListView listView2 = new ListView();
ListView listViewIguales = new ListView();

// Creamos datos de ejemplo
MiTipo miTipo1 = new MiTipo
{
    Cantidad = 1,
    Clave = "Elemento1",
    Precio = 100M,
    Hora = new TimeSpan(10, 1, 0)
};
MiTipo miTipo2 = new MiTipo
{
    Cantidad = 1,
    Clave = "Elemento2",
    Precio = 100M,
    Hora = new TimeSpan(10, 1, 0)
};
MiTipo miTipo3 = new MiTipo
{
    Cantidad = 1,
    Clave = "Elemento3",
    Precio = 100M,
    Hora = new TimeSpan(10, 1, 0)
};            
var lista1 = new List<MiTipo>
{
    miTipo1, // este está en los dos ListView
    miTipo2
};            
var lista2 = new List<MiTipo>
{
    miTipo1, // este está en los dos ListView
    miTipo3
};

// Metemos datos de ejemplo en los list view
listView1.ItemsSource = lista1;
listView2.ItemsSource = lista2;

// Aquí es donde miramos los que están en los dos ListView 
List<MiTipo> listaIguales = lista1.Intersect(lista2).ToList();
listViewIguales.ItemsSource = listaIguales;
```

Sin embargo, como te decía arriba, yo no lo haría así. Yo crearía los ListView en el XAML de la vista y haría un `Binding` en su `Itemssource` con una lista del ViewModel (lista1, lista2 y listaIguales serían propiedades públicas del ViewModel). Así listaIguales podría ser de solo lectura y estaría siempre actualizado.

Comment: Sería de agradecer que quien hace el "downvote" dejase algún comentario explicando el por qué. Así sería mucho más sencillo mejorar la respuesta. No obstante, ya la he modificado y ahora está todo explicado mucho mejor. Gracias