# ¿Como puedo unir elementos que coinciden en dos listas en una sola?

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo 2 listas lista4 y lista 5 y me arrojan los siguientes datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es unir los datos que tengan coincidencia de acuerdo al ID del producto, además de quitar la palabra ListviewSubItem, mi código es el siguiente:

```cs
public void ComparaMovimiento()
{
    Console.WriteLine("LISTA 4");
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        List<string> list4 = new List<string>(4);
        list4.Add(null); // Add empty references (BAD).
        list4.Add(null);
        list4.Add(null);
        list4.Add(null);
        list4[0] = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].ToString();
        list4[1] = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].ToString();
        list4[2] = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].ToString();
        list4[3] = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].ToString();
        string result = string.Join(",", list4.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("LISTA 5");

    for (int j = 0; j < listView2.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        List<string> list5 = new List<string>(4);
        list5.Add(null); // Add empty references (BAD).
        list5.Add(null);
        list5.Add(null);
        list5.Add(null);
        list5[0] = listView2.Items[j].SubItems[0].ToString();
        list5[1] = listView2.Items[j].SubItems[1].ToString();
        list5[2] = listView2.Items[j].SubItems[2].ToString();
        list5[3] = listView2.Items[j].SubItems[3].ToString();

        string result = string.Join(",", list5.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Como ejemplo de acuerdo a la imagen mi salida esperada seria, suponiendo que se añade a otra lista:

LISTA 6

```
1, DANER097NG255GD, $175.00, 12:23:16, 1, DANER097NG255GD, $175.00, 12:34:05
1, BUBBLARICLL16PN, $179.00, 13:10:53, 1, BUBBLARICLL16PN, $179.00, 13:17:36
1, SWEET7729NG26TD, $160.00, 17:58:24, 1, SWEET7729NG26TD, $160.00, 18:04:16
```

Comment: 1) En lugar de poner una imagen, copia y pega el texto. (Es mucho mas legible y accesible) 2) Cual es el problema con el código que has colocado? Donde esta el error, cual es el error, etc.

Comment: Revisa el método [`Union`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-6.0) de `IEnumerable`.  Creo que hace exactamente lo que necesitas

Comment: Ayer mismo preguntaron algo parecido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/497660/como-comparar-valores-iguales-de-2-listview-y-poner-los-valores-iguales-en-otr/497720#497720

Comment: ¿Por qué haces el List de string? Si quieres tener 4 campos en cada elemento de la lista, lo suyo es que crees una clase y hagas el List de esa clase que te has creado.

Comment: Cual es el tipo de datos de tus listas?